# How Webpack behaves differently when in development and production

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path')

const config = {
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

My **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "WebpackTest",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**app.js**

```
import { cube } from './maths.js';
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
root.innerHTML = `<p>Hello mate</p>${cube(5)}`;
```

**maths.js**

```
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}

export function cube(x) {
    return x * x * x;
}
```

By running `webpack -d`, **bundle.js** is 5.16kb.

By running `webpack -p`, **bundle.js** is 656 bytes.

I cannot find out how webpack tells `between -p and -d`. There is nothing inside the configuration file that `differentiates dev from prod`!! Moreover, even though there is no `Uglify` plugin, Webpack uses such a plugin as to produce *minified* bundle  when using `-p`.
Any explanation?

Comment: What you are looking for is webpack mode. You should find information if you search for this. For example: https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a

Answer (score 0):

When you add the flags webpack dynamically adds stuff to the configuration. Like the uglify plugin or the NamedModulesPlugin

So right now you're kind of half-way between being explicit on what you want webpack to do and half-way getting magic by just using the flags

https://survivejs.com/webpack/foreword/